# Could not install from "angular\core@10.0.14" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting this error when I run `npm list`

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@15.0.3, required by @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.3
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@10.0.14, required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10.0.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler-cli@^14.0.0, required by @angular-builders/custom-webpack@14.1.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@10.0.14, required by @angular/animations@10.0.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@10.0.14, required by @angular/common@10.0.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@10.0.14, required by @angular/forms@10.0.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@10.0.14, required by @angular/platform-browser@10.0.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@10.0.14, required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@10.0.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@10.0.14, required by @angular/router@10.0.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler-cli@^14.0.0, required by @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.10
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler-cli@^14.0.0, required by @ngtools/webpack@14.2.10
```

and when I tried to install the missing library using `npm install angular/core@10.0.14`

I get the following error

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "angular\core@10.0.14" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Comment: Do you really have the back slash?

Comment: I copied it from : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core/v/10.0.14 and it is with back slash

Comment: You need to run: `npm i @angular/core@10.0.14`. It's a scoped package

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail I don't see a backslash in the link, can you show the screenshot?